# how to adjust margin session flash in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to flash a success message when data store successfully. My database code and every other thing working fine but when I give $_SESSION success message it always come under navigation.

1) I want to know is there any way in php to set margin of $_SESSION['success_flash'] message
2) is there any way like /n/n type so that my flash message will show two line below
3)

My real code is:

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '\n\n<span style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">Data Saved Successfully!</span>';
```

I tried /n/n but not working:

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '\n\n<span style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">Data Saved Successfully!</span>';
```

I tried style="margin-top:200px;"  but not working:

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="margin-top:200px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">Data Saved Successfully!</span>';
```

Kindly check the image below only green background is showing under the navigation bar and the text message "Data saved successfully!" not showing because it is hidden under the navigation.

[image]

One more thing I am using below code after the flash message and my code end.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'index.php'; </script>";
```

Any idea or suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks you.

I am getting data and passing the data to database successfully. I just want to reload my page after php call and show sucess flash to the user.

My Ajax Call: top my php page.

```
<script>
function createD () {

var data = {
     'name'              : jQuery('#name').val(),
     'phone'             : jQuery('#phone').val(),
   };  

 //Ajax call Start Here
 jQuery.ajax({
   url : '/mycodpage/includes/codfile/product.php',
   method : 'POST',
   data : data,
   success : function(data){

     if (data != 'passed') {
       // This will show error
       jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html(data);
     }

     if (data == 'passed') {
       //clear the errors if any
       jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");
       location.reload();
     }
   },
   error : function (){alert("Something went wrong.");},


 });     //Ajax call End Here

  }

} // Function End

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP once loaded it does not change on the page, it is not dynamic. The way you do this is rather weird, but can be acomplished if you will set $_SESSION['success_flash'] just right after saving the data in the database, and reaload the page.

In my opinion the best way is to use ajax here, and the ajax response can change the container under the menu to "success".

But I don't know how do you send your data, is it by POST form or something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using ajax call and there after if (data == 'passed') I am using location.reload(); and in php where I end up all the things I am using above two line what I mention in my question.

Comment: instead of location.reload you could load the "Data Saved Successfully!" communicate, without the page reload. That would be more ajax approach, instead of reloading the page just to receive the communicate.

Paste your full ajax function and a part of php file where you echo "passed"; the result, and I will write the way you could resolve your case

Comment: thanks. I edit my question and add ajax call to my php page and there i am getting everything perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add display:inline-block; or display:block; in the styles of the span.

As long as dom elements behaviour can depend on outer dom objects (and you do not specify them): if it still does not work try using padding instead of margin, if it still does not work place two span tags one inside other both with inline-block.

All that stuff using $_SESSION is kinda weird, however XD... but from your description I assume that it shows already the span, but without the margin... but you should not use $_SESSION in that way.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now we are getting somewhere. But now location.reload is unnecessary, because if you will receive 'passed' answer, you can set the communicate without reloading (and without using any code in session variable, get rid of $_SESSION['success_flash']), like below.

Please note that I do not know what is the CSS class or ID of your green DIV (if any), so for this specific example I will assume, that it has a class ".msg-response"

```
<script>
function createD () {

var data = {
     'name'              : jQuery('#name').val(),
     'phone'             : jQuery('#phone').val(),
   };  

 //Ajax call Start Here
 jQuery.ajax({
   url : '/mycodpage/includes/codfile/product.php',
   method : 'POST',
   data : data,
   success : function(data){

     if (data != 'passed') {
       // This will show error
       jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html(data);
     }

     if (data == 'passed') {
       //clear the errors if any
       jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");

       // this new line will change the content of your message div
       $('div.msg-response').html('<span style="margin-top:200px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">Data Saved Successfully!</span>');

     }
   },
   error : function (){alert("Something went wrong.");},


 });     //Ajax call End Here

  }

} // Function End

</script>
```

there is also a security risk here: "if (data != 'passed')" - you will echo PHP errors (path, filename, variables, class, code row etc.) when something unpredictionary will happen, unless you will turn display_errors off on your server (display errors should be enabled only in development mode, that's a good practice).

To avoid it you can use JSON response here, handle the "error" status, "success" status, and do nothing if JSON response is different from "success" or "error".